# How to create a directory using QT (QDir) in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have been trying to create a directory in root directory of Linux. But as I am not much familiar with Linux platform I am unable to write the correct program in QT. Can you please have a look at my code and tell me where did I did mistake?

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDir>
#include <QString>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
QDir mDir;
QString mpath="/home/qtfile";
if (!mDir.exists(mpath))
{
    mDir.mkpath(mpath);
    qDebug() <<"Created";
}
else if (mDir.exists(mpath))
{
    qDebug() <<"Already existed";
}
else
{
    qDebug()<<"Directory could not be created";
}
return a.exec();
}
```

Thank you for your time and consideration

EDIT:- Thank you everyone. Now this problem is solved

Comment: Is `"/\home\qtfile"` perhaps supposed to be `"/home/qtfile"`?

Comment: @Angew i guess I tried that

Comment: I suppose you should be using mDir.mkdir instead the mkpath

Comment: Root directory of linux is typically restricted to root-access only. Better is to create a directory within your home path (which looks like is your desired action). `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation)` should give you the home path. Just append your desired directory and create it if desired. `QDir mydir(path); mydir.mkpath(desiredpath);`

Comment: @SebastianLange Can you please write a short code on that. I did not well understand your QStandardpaths syntax

Comment: @Dusteh I Have tried that

Comment: @SamratLuitel there are examples for all actions mentioned within the documentation, please refer to these.

Comment: @SebastianLange I guess If i have understood that I would not have asked that. Actually I want to know why this is not working correctly in Linux but is perfectly working in WIndows?

Comment: Listen to @SebastianLange, writing in /home requires root priviledges. If you've changed the destination, update the question's code accordingly.

Comment: First guess: Not your directory => not writable. Thats why i pointed to `QStandardPaths::writableLocation()`, which will return a path to your home directory in which you should have write permissions (or will return an empty string). The path in linux `/home` is typically root-only-writable, therefor as long as you do not intent to run this as root it will ultimativly fail by not having permissions...

Comment: @SebastianLange Thanks for that but It did not displayed a single location. So what should I do if I want to change my directory to Desktop. Will it need root permission?

Comment: @SebastianLange Thanks now it worked and Now I understood the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the issue of access rights @SamratLuitel is writing about in the comments.

Hence, you could try to give it a go in the proper home location, for example:

```
const QString& homePath = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::HomeLocation);
QDir dir(homePath);
if (dir.mkdir("somedir"))
{
    //success
}
```